# Pass new List<> object to model

Tags: c#, razor

I want to pass a new list of button options to my model for when I need to use more than one button in my view.

I have tried multiple model setups, but for some reason, my code does not see the model.

View

```cs
    @Html.Partial("_PageHeader", new FliteAdmin.ViewModels.PageHeaderViewModel { PageTitle = "Tenant onboarding",
    Buttons = new List<FliteAdmin.ViewModels.PageHeaderViewModel> {
           ButtonTitle = "Add Tenant",
           ButtonAction = "TenantDetails",
           ButtonController = "System",
           ButtonParameters = new { ID = Guid.Empty }.ToString()
        }
    })
```

Model

```
    public class PageHeaderViewModel
    {
        public string PageTitle { get; set; }
        public List<Button> Buttons { get; set; }

    }

    public class Button
    {
        public string ButtonTitle { get; set; }
        public string ButtonAction { get; set; }
        public string ButtonController { get; set; }
        public string ButtonParameters { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to pass a list of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
@Html.PartialAsync("_PageHeader", new FliteAdmin.ViewModels.PageHeaderViewModel {
   PageTitle = "Tenant onboarding",
   Buttons = new List<FliteAdmin.ViewModels.Button>() {
        new FliteAdmin.ViewModels.Button() {
            ButtonTitle = "Add Tenant",
            ButtonAction = "TenantDetails",
            ButtonController = "System",
            ButtonParameters = new { ID = Guid.Empty }.ToString()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello my colleague,
is This will fix your issue ?

```
@Html.Partial("_PageHeader",

new WebApplication1.Models.PageHeaderViewModel()
{
    PageTitle = "Tenant onboarding",

    Buttons = new List<WebApplication1.Models.Button>()
{

new WebApplication1.Models.Button
{
ButtonTitle = "Add Tenant",
ButtonAction = "TenantDetails",
ButtonController = "System",
ButtonParameters = new { ID = Guid.Empty }.ToString()
},
new WebApplication1.Models.Button
{
ButtonTitle = "Add Tenant",
ButtonAction = "TenantDetails",
ButtonController = "System",
ButtonParameters = new { ID = Guid.Empty }.ToString()
},

new WebApplication1.Models.Button
{
ButtonTitle = "Add Tenant",
ButtonAction = "TenantDetails",
ButtonController = "System",
ButtonParameters = new { ID = Guid.Empty }.ToString()
}



}
}

)
```